# Nonsymmetric permutations for LU factorisation of symmetric matrix

Tags: sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix. It is then well known that computing the LU factorisation of $PAP^T$ instead of $A$ for a suitably chosen permutation matrix $P$ can greatly reduce fill-in. My question is: Can we show that considering nonsymmetric permutations, i.e. $PAQ^T$, cannot reduce fill-in even further?

Comment: If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then you wouldn't do an LU decomposition, but an $LL^T$ (Cholesky) decomposition. It would make sense to assume that in that case, a symmetric permutation is useful because if you use a different $P$ and $Q$, the resulting matrix is no longer symmetric and you need to go back to an LU decomposition -- spending at least twice the memory and compute time.

Comment: Which I would happily accept if doing so shaves off a factor 100 for the fill-in.

Comment: I remember a theorem which basically states that for symmetric matrices A, minimum bandwidth permutation is also symmetric, though I don't remember the source. However, it is the basis of using approximate permutations like symrcm and symamd on symmetricized patterns of non-symmetric matrices to get good approximations. Also, if my memory isn't betraying me, symamd outperforms colamd when tested on matrices from Harwell-Boeing collection and SuiteSparse matrix collection.

Comment: This paper contains a discussion on ordering symmetric matrices. In general, algorithms designed for symmetric matrices are better than nonsymmetric. He notes an exception when you have specific knowledge of how $A$ was constructed. If $A = M^T M$, where $M$ may be rectangular, then performing the column permutation on $M$ will often yield better results. Its still a symmetric permutation, but uses nonsymmetric algorithms.

https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.124.1109&rep=rep1&type=pdf